# What am I missing to fix this JSONP code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

I have followed a JSONP example to send data to a cross-domain, however I get a

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': 2
>   arguments required, but only 1 present.

on the `head.insertBefore(script);` line.

What am I missing here?

```
function requestJSONP(url) {
  // create script with passed in URL
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = url;

  // after the script is loaded (and executed), remove it
  script.onload = function () {
    this.remove();
  };

  // insert script tag into the DOM (append to <head>)
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  head.insertBefore(script);
}

function processWeather(data) {
alert(data);
}


var url = 'http://www.domain.com/urls.php?callback=processWeather&format=json&cookie=jtyh65&url=thispage&key=765';

requestJSONP(url);
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why are you writing your own code to use a JSONP resource rather than using jQuery's built-in handling for JSONP?

Answer (score 3):

`insertBefore` expects two arguments. I'm pretty sure you meant

```
head.appendChild(script);
```

instead of

```
head.insertBefore(script);
```

Separately, note that the `remove` method of DOM elements is a relatively recent addition, so this line:

```
this.remove();
```

...in your `onload` handler may fail on older browsers (I'm looking at you, IE8), since `this` there is a DOM element, not a jQuery instance. You might want

```
this.parentNode.removeChild(this); // DOM
```

...or of course (as you've tagged your question jQuery):

```
$(this).remove();                  // jQuery
```

...instead.

---

As you've tagged your question `jquery`:

That said, jQuery has JSONP support [built in](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), you don't have to write it again yourself:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.domain.com/urls.php?&format=json&cookie=jtyh65&url=thispage&key=765',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
        // Use `data`, it's already been parsed for you
    },
    error: function() {
        // Something didn't work
    }
});
```

jQuery will manage creating a function for the JSONP endpoint to call back, adding the `callback=` to the URL, etc.